# Is there a way to know Who created a folder in a SharePoint Document Library and moved contents in it ?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have already gone through the Audit Log Reports in Site Collection Administration settings. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the folder still in the library or are you asking because the folder was deleted and you want to know who created/deleted it  ? If the folder is still there you can see the Created By property of the folder. Similarly view the Created By property of the documents in the folder. 

You can view this on individual items by viewing the properties or just make the "Created By" property visible in your document library view.

Comment: The folder is still present and I want to know how the files or by whom the files got into a folder?
Like for instance, say I created a blank folder and someone uploaded/moved contents in it.  Say the files are uploaded directly, then I can figure out who uploaded it, But what if the files are moved to a folder, How will I know who moved the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your documents library
2. Click "LIBRARY" in the ribbon (top left of the page)
3. Click "Modify View"
4. In the columns section tick "Created By" and "Modified By" properties
5. Scroll to the top or bottom of the page and click "OK"
6. You should now see who created / modifed each document / folder

Comment: Thanks for the answer but  I want to know how the files or by whom the files got into a folder? Like for instance, say I created a blank folder and someone uploaded/moved contents in it. Now assume the files are uploaded directly, then I can figure out who uploaded it, But what if the files are moved ( bulk ) to a folder, How will I know who moved the contents?

Answer (score 1):

If this is SharePoint Online you have access to the End User Audit Logs in the Compliance Center. Login to your tenant as a Global Administrator and access this page: https://protection.office.com/#/unifiedauditlog. If logging is not already turned on you will have to enable it. Once enabled, you will be able to report on the following activities related to files and folders:

[image: End User Audit Logs - Files and Folders]